# Parent HTML jquery plugins not working after adding child HTML in IFRAME

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a html called `parent.html` and another html called `child.html` . The child html serves as the body for the parent and i included it in the parent like this :

```
<div id ="body_Menu" style="padding-top:1em;">
    <iframe src="D:\\bodice\\bodiceMenu\child.html" width="1220" height="600" scrolling="no">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Now both the parent and child use jquery plugins. A common library is the traditional `jquery.js`:

```
<script type="text/javascript"    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

which has been included in both the parent and child as both of them have javascript/jquery animations/functions that need to run .

The problem is that, after including the child in iframe , the parent javscript has stopped running. I don't see any error in the console as well. But when both the html s are loaded separately, they run perfectly .

I am using these two plugins :

```
<script src="jquery-css-transform.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What is the problem here ? How can i rectify it ? Any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

As i can see, your iframe take its source from a local file (D:\bodice\bodiceMenu\child.html). If you display your page from a web server (even a local server on your machine), you won't be authorized to display your iframe due to security reason on most browsers (this is the case in chrome for example). Is that what you're trying to do ?

Comment: There is no web server involved. Its a normal html file , injected via iframe. I did not mention web server any where ...And the iframe is getting displayed properly. Thats not the question as well. Understand my question properly . The javascript in the parent is not working . I want to know why is that ...

Comment: Wow easy dude, i'm trying to help you :) So i misread, i thought the js in child frame was not executing. Do you have any online demo that I could test locally on my machine ?

Comment: Ahhh... you misunderstood me again, man ... I was not chiding you, rather telling you to read the question. Sorry, if that came out a bit loud.. I don't have an online working demo right now.. It's a local set up. Probably, when i get a bit more time, i will fiddle it out and post the fiddle as well.